# Usage of "vereinzelt" / Bedeutung von "vereinzelt"

Tags: word-usage, grammatical-number

In [diesem Video](http://youtu.be/v0hVzaA1_FU?t=10m5s) (10:05) spricht der Altkanzler Helmut Schmidt. Wenn ich richtig verstanden habe:

> Wenn man sich die Gemeinschaft der Europäer [ *EU-Länder* ] vorstellt, als eine die in der Eurozone vereinzelt, dann werden nicht alle Mitglieder dieser Eurozone sein.

Ich kann es nicht ganz verstehen. Nachdem ich im Duden ([vereinzelt](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/vereinzelt) und [vereinzeln](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/vereinzeln)) gesucht habe, scheint mir, dass man keinen einzelnen Gegenstand nochmal "vereinzeln" kann. Der Kontext hilft mir nicht viel.

**Kann mir jemand die Verwendung von "vereinzeln" mit einer Singularform als Objekt, oder die Bedeutung in diesem Kontext erklären?**

---

In [this video](http://youtu.be/v0hVzaA1_FU?t=10m5s) (10:05) we can hear former federal Chancellor Helmut Schmidt say (please correct if wrong):

> Wenn man sich die Gemeinschaft der Europäer vorstellt, als eine die in der Euro-zone vereinzelt, dann werden nicht Alle Mitglieder dieser Euro-zone sein.

I can't understand the meaning of "vereinzelt" in this case, because you can't "reduce to singular elements" a singular thing.

Comment: Thx for editing. Shouldn't "alle" be written "Alle" ("nicht Alle werden Mitglieder in der ... sein", as opposed to "nicht alle Mitglieder werden... sein") ?

Answer (score 5):

You heard it wrong. He says "vereint sind". "vereint" means "united". "Vereinzelt" would make no sense in this context.

What he says is:

"Wenn man sich die Gemeinschaft der Europäer vorstellt, als eine [Gemeinschaft], die in der Eurozone vereint sind[sic!], dann [...]"

"If you think of the European community as one which is united in the Euro zone, then [...]"

Comment: Müsste es nicht "vereint ist" heissen?

Comment: Ja, du hast völlig recht. Er sagt "vereint sind", aber grammatikalisch korrekt müsste es "vereint ist" heißen. Das ist ein Flüchtigkeitsfehler von Schmidt. So etwas kommt vor, wenn man sich eine komplizierte Formulierung überlegt und gleichzeitig spricht.

Comment: ok thank you but it still makes little sense, regarding the other half of the sentence...damn Herr Schmidt is getting old

Comment: Don't worry, I'm a native speaker and I too don't understand what he wants to say.